# Define a constant table in BigQuery (or Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery

How do I define in a simple single line a temporary constant table in BigQuery (or Postgres the syntax of which will likely work in BigQuery)?

```sql
with my_fruits as (
--- ??? define a table 
--- consisting of a single column fruit_name
--- with values ('apple', 'pear', 'gooseberry', ...  (12 more fruits))
)
select * from my_fruits left join 
(select fruit_name, 1 is_present from my_dataset.your_fruits)
using (fruit_name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest):

```
select * from unnest(['apple', 'pear', 'gooseberry']) as fruit_name
```

You also can join with UNNEST [directly](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays).

Answer (score 1):

With Postgres you can easily create a multi-column constant table:

```
select * from (values (1,1,1), (1,2,3)) as x(one, two, three)
```

Unfortunately above doesn't work for BigQuery and not sure if there is a proper substitute for it.

Comment: Here is the BigQuery way: `select * from unnest(array<struct<one int64, two int64, three int64>>[(1, 1, 1),(1, 2, 3)])` or just `select * from unnest(array[(1, 1, 1),(1, 2, 3)])`